# Cloud function error : fcm.googleapis.com network timeout. Please try again

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-functions, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-admin

I tried to write a function to send a data message to users who are in a group whenever there is a new post in that group. Sometimes my code gives this error:

```
Couldn't send message to +XXXXXXXXXXXX:  { Error: fcm.googleapis.com network timeout. Please try again.  
at FirebaseAppError.Error (native)
at FirebaseAppError.FirebaseError [as constructor] (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/utils/error.js:39:28)
at FirebaseAppError.PrefixedFirebaseError [as constructor] (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/utils/error.js:85:28)
at new FirebaseAppError (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/utils/error.js:119:28)
at TLSSocket.<anonymous> (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/utils/api-request.js:151:51)
at emitNone (events.js:86:13)
at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:185:7)
at TLSSocket.Socket._onTimeout (net.js:338:8)
at ontimeout (timers.js:386:11)
at tryOnTimeout (timers.js:250:5)  
errorInfo:  
{ code: 'app/network-timeout',
 message: 'fcm.googleapis.com network timeout. Please try again.' },  
 codePrefix: 'app' }
```

This is the cloud function I wrote -

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

exports.sendNewPostNotifications = functions.database.ref('/classes/{classCode}/posts/{pushId}')
  .onCreate(event => {
    const classCode = event.params.classCode;
    const post = event.data.val();

    return admin.database().ref(`classes/${classCode}/name`).once('value').then(function(snapshot) {
      const className = snapshot.val();

      const payload = {
        'data': {
          'type': 'post',
          'post_id': post.time + "",
          'post_class_name': className + "",
          'post_class_code': classCode + "",
          'post_title': post.title + "",
          'post_description': post.description + "",
          'post_postedByName': post.postedByName + ""
        }
      };

      return admin.database().ref(`classes/${classCode}/participants`).once('value').then(function(participantsSnapshot) {
        var promises = [];
        participantsSnapshot.forEach(function(participant) {
          const phone = participant.val().phone;
          var promise = admin.database().ref(`users/${phone}`).once('value').then(function(user) {
            return admin.messaging().sendToDevice(user.val().token, payload).catch(reason => {
              console.log(`Couldn't send message to ${phone} : `, reason);
            });
          }).catch(reason => {
            console.log('Reason : ', reason);
          });
          promises.push(promise);
        });
        return Promise.all(promises).catch(reason => {
          console.log('Reason : ', reason);
        });
      }).catch(reason => {
        console.log('Reason : ', reason);
      });
    });
  });
```

This functions even take up to 30 seconds to execute sometimes:

```
Function execution took 30371 ms, finished with status: 'ok'
```

What should I do to correct this?

Comment: So, you're saying that *sometimes*, the network request for sending a message fails?  Network failures are a fact of life, even for Cloud Functions.

Comment: @DougStevenson Yes! In approximately 30% cases this error shows up.
I guess my script is correct?

Comment: I didn't check it exhaustively for errors, but a network timeout seems like something that could occasionally happen for any network request.  That's not typically a software problem.  I'd raise an issue with Firebase support if it's frequent.  https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/troubleshooting/

Comment: Same here for me. I guess token is not correct somehow so firebase can not find user

Comment: @Mehr , May be it's possible. But recently I updated my database and the cloud script, after which it isn't showing such error for users not found by firebase.

Comment: @RishavAgarwal How to "updated my database and the cloud script". Please help. I have the same issue.

Comment: @anhtu Actually I was nesting the promises which I was forced to do according to my database design. I guess this error occurs because of nested promises which is a bad practice. So to avoid that, I improved my database design (which caused data redundancy, but that's ok if they are properly managed).
Hope this also helps you! :)

Comment: @RishavAgarwal thank you. I fixed my issue also. Using promise for sending notification

Comment: @anhtu That's great!
But were you nesting your promises? I read somewhere that nested promises causes performance issues?

Comment: @RishavAgarwal I didn't use nested promises. I used promise chaining. Nested is always not good at all,  I think